# Android - How do I open varying files from res folder?

Tags: android, file, relative-path

Ok, so far all the answers I've found seem to be answered to by people who do not know the answer...
This should be a simple one (free rep for you yay):

I have a file in res/raw/ called overworld_a.tmx

I need to load it using the path as a string then the filename added to the string, since it varies.

Like so:

```
    String mapName = "overworld_a.tmx";
    try {
        TMXMapReader mapReader = new TMXMapReader();
        map = mapReader.readMap("raw/"+mapName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while reading the map:\n" + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
```

Problem is, this obviously doesn't work.... Simple Question is, what is the relative path to that file?

And if this is not a possibility:

Complex question is, how do I open varying files from res folder and its children?

Comment: Have You checked http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html - To open these resources with a raw InputStream, call Resources.openRawResource() with the resource ID, which is R.raw.filename ?

Comment: Why are you using res when u have assets folder ?? Is using res is necessary ??

Comment: I can't use a command that converts my file to a stream since the parameter I need to put is a filename... not a stream. This is why I'm not using openRawResource or the asset thing... Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read `overworld_a.tmx` from `res/raw` dir as :

**1.** use `openRawResource` for reading `overworld_a.tmx` as `InputStream` from raw folder :

```
String mapName = "overworld_a"; //<< just pass name without file extension 

resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mapName, "raw", getPackageName());
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(resID);
```

**2.** Get `ByteArrayOutputStream` from `inputStream` :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//... your code for reading byteArray from inputStream
```

**3.** Pass `byteArrayOutputStream` to `mapReader.readMap` :

```
 TMXMapReader mapReader = new TMXMapReader();
 map = mapReader.readMap(byteArrayOutputStream);
//.....
```

Comment: Ok, so passing a filename with its path is impossible, got it.

Comment: @DominicGrenier : it's possible to pass name for getting file from res/raw folder

Comment: But why do I need all that mumbo jumbo? Is that because the whole thing is generated in bytecode or something like it? It'd be a good addition to the answer.

Comment: Hmm seems, like I need to extend Activity, I'm already extending something else...

Comment: @DominicGrenier : u need to use Context for accessing Resources.  no need to extend Activity if your current class is pure java class just pass Context from Activity, Service or any other Application component from which u are calling this method